# Implementing Thrift Server in iOS

Tags: ios, thrift

How do you implement the server side in iOS using thrift? Using the thrift wiki, I was able to figure out how to write a client using thrift, but there seems to be no documentation in writing the server. Any example code would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK You can't have the server in Objective C as only the client bindings are supported. You can however use the C/C++ server bindings. What is your use case? It seems odd to have the server on an iOS device.

Here is the [link](http://wiki.apache.org/thrift/ThriftUsageC++) to the C++ usage docs.